# Update value using the direct path instead of "an object"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

is it possible to update a direct path in firebase instead of the object of the path?

for example, instead of this: (which works)

```
newsRef = db.ref("/news")
newsRef.update({
            image: imageURL
          });
```

do something like this? (which does not work)

```
newsRef = db.ref("/news/image")
    newsRef.update(imageURL)
```

Comment: What does it do, if not what you expect?

Comment: Try the second one, it will give you the following error "Error: Reference.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace.". As the documentation says update's "values argument contains multiple property-value pairs", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update

Comment: Using vuejs and firebase, I have a function that uploads an image to firebase storage,  then takes the storage path and saves it to the firebase database.  The code above is the database save part.  The first code example works, however I would prefer to specify a direct firebase db path to the item 'image' of the object.  This way, when building a reusable component I only need to include 1 'prop' instead of 2, i.e. sourceToUpdate="/news/image", instead of sourceToUpdate="/news" itemToUpdate="image".

Comment: Doug Stevenson... that name seemed familiar... yep I've watched all your Firebase videos on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc.  Firebase is awesome!  And thank you for your tutorials!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, the first argument for the `update` method must be an object containing the children to replace.

You have two solutions:

**1/ Passing the props as a string** (Not the most elegant.... but if you really want)

You pass only one string prop to your component as follow:

```
<upload-component path="/news/image"></upload-component>
```

and in the component:

```
  props: ['path'],
  ....

  methods: {
    saveToDb: function (imageUrl) {
      
        const pathElems = this.path.split('/');

        const ref = firebase.database().ref(pathElems[1]);

        const imageObj = {};  
        imageObj[pathElems[2]] = imageURL;  //Using the square brackets method 
        ref.update(imageObj);

    }
  }
```

**2/ Passing the props as an object**

See the Vue.js doc https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object

```
imageProps: {
  node: '/news',
  key: 'image'
}
```

then

```
<upload-component v-bind="imageProps"></upload-component>
```

and in the component:

```
  methods: {
    saveToDb: function (imageUrl) {
      
        const ref = firebase.database().ref(this.node);

        const imageObj = {};  
        imageObj[this.key] = imageURL; 
        ref.update(imageObj);

    }
  }
```